# Achieve case insensitivity for cloudant queries

Tags: cloudant, case-insensitive, parameterized-query

My query has the following selector,

```
{
  "selector": {
    "_id": {
      "$gt": null
    },
    "series": {
      "$regex": "(?i)mario"
    }
  }
}
```

Now, if I have a document with `series = mario12`, the above query is returning this document which shouldn't happen. I want my query to only ignore the case of "mario".

How can I achieve case insensitivity?

Comment: Your regular expression matches wider than what you intended. It matches 'mario' case-insensitively, sure, but anywhere in the string. Anchor at the start and end of the string, as markwatsonatx suggests below.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure I understand the question exactly. If you only want to match the full word "mario" in a case-insensitive manner then you would use a selector like this:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "_id": {
      "$gt": null
    },
    "series": {
      "$regex": "^(?i)mario$"
    }
  }
}
```

This will match "mario", "Mario", "MARIO", etc, but will not match "mario12", "Mario12", "12Mario", etc.